# Does ActiveRecord object not have instance variables for it's attributes but only methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails I have the following model:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name , :description , 
        :t_baking , :t_cooling , :t_cooking ,:t_rest

    # other stuff here

end
```

with `t_baking` , `t_cooling` , `t_cooking` ,`t_rest` as [`Time`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html).

So In my view I want to loop on each value.

```
<% ['cooking', 'baking', 'cooling' , 'rest'].each do |time| %>
    <% time_of_recipe = @recipe.instance_variable_get("@t_#{time}") %>
    <% if time_of_recipe.is_a? Time %>
        <%= time_of_recipe.strftime "%H:%M"  %>
    <% else %>
        <%= time_of_recipe %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't work because

```
@recipe.instance_variable_get("@t_cooking").class # give NilClass
```

but

```
@recipe.t_cooking.class # give Time
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@recipe.instance_variable_get("@t_cooking")
```

returns `nil` because there is no instance variable `@t_cooking` for `@recipe`.

It is a bunch of **methods** defined by ActiveRecord that you have access to, but these are not **instance variables**.

Applying it to your code, you'd want to change it to:

```
time_of_recipe = @recipe.public_send("t_#{time}")
```

Also, it is pointless to save single letter of typing.

It would be much more readable to do the following:

```
<% %w(t_cooking t_baking t_cooling t_rest).each do |time| %>
    <% time_of_recipe = @recipe.public_send(time) %>
    # ...
```

## EDIT

If you want to check available instance variables (you look to be using Rails 3.2, so your output might be slightly different):

```
@recipe.instance_variables
#=> [:@attributes, <============ this one is of particular interest
#     :@aggregation_cache,
#     :@association_cache,
#     :@readonly,
#     :@destroyed,
#     :@marked_for_destruction,
#     :@destroyed_by_association,
#     :@new_record,
#     :@txn,
#     :@_start_transaction_state,
#     :@transaction_state
#   ]
```

So you see, that it defines one instance variable `@attributes`, that holds all attributes.